# XMLNodeList/XPath - looping, but getting same first node over and over

Tags: c#, xpath, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

What have I forgetten?  Seems like I've done this before with no issues. 
As I loop through the XmlNodeList, I want to get the values of each node, but I seem to be getting the first node over and over.

```
string strXpathHL1Loop = "//*[local-name()='HLLoop1']";
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc856.SelectNodes(strXpathHL1Loop);
Console.WriteLine("Number HLLoop1 nodes=" + nodeList.Count);  

int lineNum = 0;
int loopNum = 0; 

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    loopNum++; 
    Console.WriteLine("\n-----LoopNum=" + loopNum);
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);   
    string xpathHL01 = "//HL01";
    XmlNode HL01Node = node.SelectSingleNode(xpathHL01);
    Console.WriteLine("HL01Node.OuterXml=" + HL01Node.OuterXml); 
    Console.WriteLine("HL01=" + HL01Node.InnerText);

    string xpathHl03 = "//HL03"; 
    XmlNode Hl03Node = node.SelectSingleNode(xpathHl03);
    Console.WriteLine("HL03Node.OuterXml=" + Hl03Node.OuterXml);
    Console.WriteLine("HL03=" + Hl03Node.InnerText); 
}


-----LoopNum=1
<ns0:HLLoop1 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"><ns0:
HL><HL01>1</HL01><HL02 /><HL03>S</HL03></ns0:HL><ns0:TD5><TD501>B</TD501><TD505>
UNSP_CG</TD505></ns0:TD5><ns0:DTM_2><DTM01>011</DTM01><DTM02>20190425</DTM02></n
s0:DTM_2></ns0:HLLoop1>
HL01Node.OuterXml=<HL01>1</HL01>
HL01=1
HL03Node.OuterXml=<HL03>S</HL03>
HL03=S

-----LoopNum=2
<ns0:HLLoop1 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006"><ns0:
HL><HL01>2</HL01><HL02>1</HL02><HL03>O</HL03></ns0:HL><ns0:PRF><PRF01>287775</PR
F01></ns0:PRF></ns0:HLLoop1>
HL01Node.OuterXml=<HL01>1</HL01>
HL01=1
HL03Node.OuterXml=<HL03>S</HL03>
HL03=S
```

Expected result of loop 2:

```
HL01=2
HL03Node.OuterXml=<HL03>O</HL03>
HL03=O
```

Here's the minimal data to reproduce:

```
<ns0:X12_00401_856 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006">
    <ns0:HLLoop1>
        <ns0:HL>
            <HL01>1</HL01>
            <HL02/>
            <HL03>S</HL03>
        </ns0:HL>
    </ns0:HLLoop1>
    <ns0:HLLoop1>
        <ns0:HL>
            <HL01>2</HL01>
            <HL02>1</HL02>
            <HL03>O</HL03>
        </ns0:HL>
    </ns0:HLLoop1>
</ns0:X12_00401_856>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a path going downwards relative to the `node` context node so e.g.

```
string xpathHL01 = ".//HL01";
```

or

```
string xpathHL01 = "descendant::HL01";
```

Your attempts starting with `/` start searching/selecting from the root node/document node of the context node so you end up with same node with each selection.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't understand... // is the shortcut for descendant, is it not? http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html.  Also my variable "Node" should contain only what I selected?  Does it still contain the entire XML Document?

Comment: No idea where you got the idea that using `SelectNodes` or `SelectSingleNode` or using XPath in general extracts nodes from a certain document, it simply selects them, the complete document structure doesn't change and often this is helpful to navigate with XPath to siblings, ancestors, preceding or following nodes and not only to descendants. So `node` is an `XmlNode` instance but is part of a document tree. That cheat sheet is wrong `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#path-abbrev, "`//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`"